# How can I align the column content vertically and set column width fitted?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Visual Studio 2017; ASP.NET Core MVC; Razor; bootstrap

This is the part of my `cshtml-file`:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <colgroup>
        <col />
        <col style="width:auto; white-space:nowrap" />
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model) {
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align:central">@item.TemplateName</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                        <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" title="Редактировать">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"
                                  aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" title="Копировать">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"
                                  aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" title="Удалить">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"
                                  aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The result is not the same like I expected:

[image]

I need the content of first column would be centered vertically. Also I need the second column width would be fitted according its content.

How can I get it?

Comment: Maybe you start by using property values that actually exist, instead of making up your own (`vertical-align:central`)

Comment: Try to use `vertical-align: middle` instead of `central`. Because `central` doesn't exist in css

Comment: Thank you. I used `central` because IntelliSense adviced me to use `central`. The `middle` works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please have look on this
http://plnkr.co/edit/I8XBE1kAG8qd0ivWRDhS?p=preview

```
vertical-align:middle //align vertically middle

<td style="width:1%;white-space:nowrap">
<div class="btn-group pull-right" style="width: auto;min-width: 120px;">
//to fit column width according to its content.
```